# Share Content on facebook from an Android App

Tags: android, html, dotnetopenauth, facebook-social-plugins

I am able share my content on facebook mobile app using 2 ways

**1 way is using native android coding** .In this I am able to share the content for already **logged in facebook account** in mobile and **coming back** to my android app.
The problem in this way is If the user is not logged in its showing login page. As soon as I logged in, I have no way to **come back to my android application** again. Here on i fly in facebook app only.

How to solve this Issue..?

**2 way is using html**. In this Case for both **looged in user** and **not logged in users**  cannot come back to the previous application after sharing.

How to resolve the issue..?

Comment: Which `Facebook SDK` version you are using?

Comment: I am Using FB SDK v3.7

Comment: It is working fine for me. if not logged, Showing loggin page --> share page, When i click back. It comes fine to my application.

Comment: which version do you use for that. Can I have a sample for that